# for loop only returns the last value

Tags: python, list, for-loop, twitter, nested-loops

I am new to python and I am doing a project on fetching tweets.  I was able to do so and now I want to get the hashtags from all those tweets. But when I tried to do a for loop in order to append my list, it only captures the last item/values.  I've been all over google and even tried chatGPT but I could not seem to get it right.

Here is my code if anyone is kind to please look and see what I am missing.

```
keyword = str(input("Enter hashtag"))
date = str(input("Enter date: YYYY-MM-DD"))

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=keyword, since_id=date, lang='en', tweet_mode = "extended",).items(30) # this is correct

#created columns for Dataframe
columns = ['Date & Time', 'User', 'Retweet_no' ,'Text', 'Location'] 
data_la= [] 

#Created for loop to append data_la 
for tweet in tweets:
  data_la.append([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.full_text, tweet.geo])
print(tweet.full_text)  
## trying to get hashtags of tweets fetched. 
#Get the tweet text
  tweet_text = tweet.full_text
#Use a regex to find all hashtags in the tweet text
  hashtags = re.findall(r"#(\w+)", tweet_text)
  print('items:', hashtags)
  # Use the entities attribute to get the hashtags

hashtag_list = []
for word in tweets:
     if word == '#':
       hashtag_list.append(word)
print('List:', hashtag_list)
```

I've been everywhere on google trying to find the answer but to no avail. I have been stuck with this problem for over a week now.

Comment: It might be because you are only appending the word if the whole word is a hashtag, not checking whether the start character is a hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

As RedzMakersError said, you only check if the word is `#`, and only `#`.

You should try something like:

```
 if word.startswith('#'):
   hashtag_list.append(word)
```

As the name of the function says, it returns `True` if the string starts with `#`, `False` otherwise.

Official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Do you think I should put all the tweets first on a string before I can pick the words out?  Because what I am trying is picking up the hashtags directly from the tweets I've acquired.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that with this line:

```
if word == '#':
```

you check if the word is only a "#"

You probaly just want to check if the word starts with a hashtag character (as hashtags do). You can do that with the `startswith()` function wich checks if a string starts with the given character and returns `true` if it does.

So in youre case your code should probably look like this:

```
if word.startswith("#"):
    hashtag_list.append(word)
```

Here you can read a bit more about `startswith()`:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_startswith.asp

hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! I tried it now and it looks like it works but it only returns the last value/items of the last tweet fetched and not for all of the tweets.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your tweets list that you loop through. Could you edit your question to show us how u get the tweets list?

Comment: Thank you for quickly answering me! Edited my codes now.  :).

Comment: I have an idea: maybe the problem is that you are iterating over your `tweets` but you actually want to iterate over the `words` in the `tweet`. I've written a small gist for the code that i think should solve your problem [check it out](https://gist.github.com/vince-vibin/a5f94f47db40d5471a5a7ca10acebd71). If it still doesnt work feel free to let me know :). (Sorry for the long answer)